# Model object has no attribute HyperlinkedRelatedField

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-drf-renderer

I've checked dozens of examples and I think I am doing it the right way, however I am getting this error message 'City' object has no attribute 'store', Please help, see my serializer enclosed.

```
class CitySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    store = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name = 'store:listStoreByCity',read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = City
        read_only_fields = ['location']
        fields = [
                "city", 
                "latitude", 
                "longitude",
                "store",
                "state", 
                "img", 
                "location",
            ]
```

Models.py

```
from django.contrib.gis.db import models
from localflavor.us.us_states import STATE_CHOICES


class City(models.Model):
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    latitude = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=11, default=0)
    longitude = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=11, default=0)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=STATE_CHOICES, null=True, blank=True)
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img', blank=True)
    location = models.PointField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.city)
```

Comment: show model definition of `City`

Comment: I have posted my models.py

Comment: so ... there is no `store` field in model definition

Comment: Store is store = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField, are you familiar with DRF

Comment: ok. but it is missing in read_only_fields

Comment: I have tried that not helping

Comment: store = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name = 'store:listStoreByCity',read_only=True)

Answer (score 0):

By default DRF will look at a related objects through the `store` name which you don't have in your model.

Either set the related_name to "store" or use the source serializer's field's argument source in the serializer's `store` and set it to `"store_set"`.

If this is still unclear to you, have a look on these case described in tutorial http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#adding-information-to-our-model

Comment: AttributeError
Exception Value: 
'City' object has no attribute 'store__set'

Comment: Not working,  got an unexpected keyword argument 'related_name'

Comment: @ArtYudin if you could share the repo (at least the part concerning problem)  then I will be glad to try helping. Remember to share versions of django and drf